# New Internet Connection in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ethernet

My ISP provided me the Ethernet Cable only and no router and configured the new network connection in Windows using username, password and service name (using dialup). How to setup this connection in Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your provider gave you a cable, a username and a password, it means that the way to connect is with probably using PPPoE (Point-to-Point Protocol over Ethernet). The easiest way to do that is using the included network manager applet.

- Right click on the network icon in the right-top margin of the screen, and click in edit connections
- Click in add
- In connection type, select DSL
- Fill the fields using the information that your provider gave to you and click save

Now, you can see your connection clicking in the network icon and your created connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this documentation provided in ubuntu wiki "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/SetUpDialer". Hope this might help.